# Swift 2 - change UIView background colour from another UIViewControl

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I am trying to change the colour of a `UIView` in View Controller when a button is pressed in Collection View Controller.

In my `UIViewController` I have a function that changes the color when this function is called from collection view controller the function prints out but the colour is not changed.

View Controller

```
 static let sharedInstance = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("settingPageId") as! SettingsViewController

        @IBOutlet weak var TopView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let colorsViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("colorsViewCollection")
        self.addChildViewController(colorsViewController!)
        colorCollectionView.addSubview((colorsViewController!.view)!)
}

    func colorHasBeenSelected(){

            TopView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() // color is not changed if called from collection view
            print("colorHasBeenSelected") // it prints ok

        }
```

Collection View Controller

```
let settingPage = SettingsViewController.sharedInstance

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        _ = settingPage.view // without it TopView returns nil
}

@IBAction func colorAction(sender: UIButton) {

settingPage.colorHasBeenSelected()
}
```

How can I make the `UIView` inside `UIViewController` change the background colour from the `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Your sharedInstance is not the controller displayed on your screen because you create a new instance of it by calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.
You can use the NSNotificationCenter to post a message when the color change or use a protocol

Comment: Thank you! and how can a pass a String using SNotificationCenter ?

Comment: Use the postNotification with userInfo method
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo: